# SVN How to revert changes from a feature branch

Tags: svn, branch, revert

I had created a feature branch and committed there several times. I need to revert some files as if I've never touched them in my feature branch. In other words I don't want to reintegrate them back.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly, your situation is following:

1. You've created a featured branch:

   ```
   $ svn cp ^/trunk/ ^/branches/feature
   ```
2. You've did some work on `^/branches/feature` and commited.

   ```
   $ ... work, work, work ...
   $ svn ci
   ```
3. Now you want to undo some changes.
   So, do a reverse merge.
   First, check which revisions you want to undo using `svn log`:

   ```
   In your featured branch working copy:
   $ svn log -v 
   -----------------------------------
   r234 ...
   Changed paths:
   M /branches/featured/file.c       

   Implemented a feature
   -----------------------------------
   ```
4. Reverse-merge the specific revision(s). Note the `-` before the revision:

   ```
   $ svn merge -c -234 .
   ```
5. Reintegrate to the trunk:

   ```
   In the trunk working copy:
   $ svn merge --reintegrate ^/branches/feature .
   ```

Comment: That's exactly what I need! But I can't revert the whole commit. Just one file in several commits. The other thing why a can't just undo the changes with tortoise SVN is that I've renamed the feature branch.

Comment: @dmiandre, you can reverse-merge specific files: 
$ svn merge -c -234 path/to/file

Answer (score 0):

If you do a merge from one branch to another, you will only merge the diffs that happened on the first branch. If you don't have touched files, there will no diff for them, so there will be no part of the reintegration that touches these files. So no, you don't have to revert anything. Doing `revert` reverts the changes you have done in a working copy on the client, and has nothing to do with branches or the repository.

Comment: Yes, and I need a counterpart of revert command that works with repository and will return some files in feature branch to the state they were at the moment of creating the feature branch.